# Scala Spark job to upload CSV file data to mongo DB fails due to CodecConfigurationException

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, codec

I'm new to both spark and scala. I'm trying to upload a csv file to Mongo DB using a spark job in Scala.

On upload, facing the following error during the job execution,

org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class .

Path to input file will be passed during the execution.

I'm kind of stuck with this issue for past 2 days. Any help to overcome this issue is appreciated.

Thanks.

I have tried it for uploading to elastic search and it worked like a charm.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import com.mongodb.spark._
import com.mongodb.spark.config.WriteConfig
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SaveMode, SparkSession}
import com.test.Config


object MongoUpload {
    val host = <host>
    val user = <user>
    val pwd = <password>
    val database = <db>
    val collection = <collection>
    val uri = "mongodb://${user}:${pwd}@${host}/"
    val NOW = java.time.LocalDate.now.toString

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("Mongo-Test-Upload")
      .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", uri)
      .getOrCreate()

    spark
      .read
      .format("csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .load(args(0))
      .rdd
      .map(toEligibility)
      .saveToMongoDB(
        WriteConfig(
            Map(
                "uri" -> uri,
                "database" -> database,
                "collection" -> collection
            )
        )
      )
   }


  def toEligibility(row: Row): Eligibility =
    Eligibility(
      row.getAs[String]("DATE_OF_BIRTH"),
      row.getAs[String]("GENDER"),
      row.getAs[String]("INDIVIDUAL_ID"),
      row.getAs[String]("PRODUCT_NAME"),
      row.getAs[String]("STATE_CODE"),
      row.getAs[String]("ZIPCODE"),
      NOW
    )
}

case class Eligibility (
  dateOfBirth: String,
  gender: String,
  recordId: String,
  ProductIdentifier: String,
  stateCode: String,
  zipCode: String,
  updateDate: String
)
```

Spark job fails with the following error, Caused by: org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class Eligibility

Comment: Check if this link helps: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.7/driver/getting-started/quick-start-pojo/

Comment: Doesn't contain any info about spark job configuration. Thanks for the response though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either map to a `Document` of the desired format or convert to a `Dataset` and then save it eg:

```
    import spark.implicits._
    spark
      .read
      .format("csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .load(args(0))
      .rdd
      .map(toEligibility)
      .toDS()
      .write()
      .format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource")
      .options(Map("uri" -> uri,"database" -> database, "collection" -> collection)
      .save()
   }
```

Comment: Hi Ross, I'm facing the following error in line .toDS[Eligibility]() - method toDS: ()org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[com.optum.ohhl.nhi.mongo.BEligibility] does not take type parameters

Comment: Then I removed the type params and tried .toDS().saveToMongoDB(..), again I end up with the following error, value saveToMongoDB is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset

Comment: Updated the example - now using the `write()` api.  You actually should be able to just select the columns you want in the original csv dataframe and use alias to rename them.  But that may be an exercise for the future.

Comment: Hi @Ross, Is there a way I can modify the above code to avoid duplicate entries being inserted into mongo DB?. How can I restrict duplicate entries based on a unique field value, say identifier?.

Comment: @dwarakeshtp can you accept this as an answer if this worked for you. So that it is helpful for others